# Meerkat H1 General BMX

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I have a bike on which I’m looking for information. Serial number is T80409c3 I believe.  Has been stored in a garage and has all original parts minus the kickstand that was aftermarket. I believe it to be a prototype.

It’s a Chromoly frame.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest googling before asking - its unlikely to be a prototype based on all those results.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I see little difference between the general shape of the L1 and the H1,  so it was probably more of a configuration difference, a price bracket.  I googled for   'Meerkat H1 General BMX'  and got a bunch of relevant results, like https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=209951   and there are interesting titbits like **F-1 racing was a short lived fad from 1987–1989 that involved bicycles with 20" wheels that looked like a cross between BMX, Road Race Touring and Mountain bicycles**   and https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=556724 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_Juarez

Comment: Ok. So you know a lot of people with this bike?

Comment: @MikeErsfeld I've never heard of them before this question, but our good friend Google knows all about them.

Answer (score 1):

You have a F1 racing BMX - probably from around the late 1980s.

They have 20" wheels and generally steel frames, and often feature BMX style brakes, and the crankset on this one is a one-piece construction.

Differences to regular BMXs, they are built with derailleur gears and a sloped top-tube.  Also, the bars are not traditional BMX ones but are either short flat bars or somewhat aero bars to encourage a lower more-aero position.  Some brands even fitted non-round biopace chainrings to appeal to the racer crowd.  Even disk wheels were fitted to some, for added aero benefits.

[image: https://bmxsociety.com/uploads/monthly_01_2011/post-3433-129605771601.jpg]

There are many more photos at https://bmxsociety.com/topic/48820-general-meerkat-l1-m1/   Notice the disproportionally long cranks too - that seems to be common, showing it was more about straight line power than manoeverability or tricks and stunts.

You're right - these would not have been kickstand bikes so that's definitely after fitment.